# AVX2 Function To Set a Bit to 1 performs the same as SSE2

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation, sse, avx

I have these two loops to set a bit (change a 0 to a 1, leave existing 1s alone) in a 16-bit signed integer array and do that for an entire array.

As in

- Index 0: 0000000000000001
- Index 1: 0000000000000001
- Index 2: 0000000000000001

Call function with 'pos' set to 4

- Index 0: 0000000000010001
- Index 1: 0000000000010001
- Index 2: 0000000000010001

The output is correct, but the AVX2 version runs in almost exactly the same time as the SSE2 version with no improvement. I'm using an Intel i7 7700K @ 4.2 GHz.

SSE2

```
 const int32_t p = static_cast<int32_t>(pos);//Cast to correct type for ISA
 __m128i _source, _DESTi;

 const __m128i _one = _mm_set1_epi16(static_cast<int16_t>(1));
 const __m128i _shifted_left = _mm_slli_epi16(_one, p);      

for (size_t i = 0uz; (i + 8) < end; i += 8)
{
     //Set Values
     _source = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*) & source[i]);
    
    _DESTi = _mm_or_si128(_shifted_left, _source);
                            
    //Store Result
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*) & source[i], _DESTi);
}//End for
```

AVX2

```
 const int32_t p = static_cast<int32_t>(pos);//Cast to correct type for ISA

 __m256i _source, _DESTi;                   

 const __m256i _one = _mm256_set1_epi16(static_cast<int16_t>(1));
 const __m256i _shifted_left = _mm256_slli_epi16(_one, p);

 for (size_t i = 0uz; (i + 16) < end; i += 16)
 {
      //Set Values
      _source = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*) &source[i]);

     _DESTi = _mm256_or_si256(_shifted_left, _source);                      

     //Store Result
     _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)&source[i], _DESTi);
}//End for
```

Scaler

```
 for (size_t i = 0uz; i < end; ++i)
 {
       source[i] = (1ull << pos) | source[i];
 }
```

I suspect my AVX512 implementation may also show no improvement, but I can't test that as my i7 7700K lacks AVX512. Is there any way I can optimize either of these loops further. To be clear both of these are a monumental improvement over the scaler version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 16-byte loads/stores can saturate DRAM bandwidth, and probably L3.  Test multiple passes over an array that fits in L2 cache (256K).  Also, any decent compiler will hoist the loop invariant `_temp = _mm_slli_epi16(_one, p);` for you, but it's weird that you put it inside the loop as a separate statement, as if it needed to be re-computed each iteration.  Make sure you're compiling with optimization enabled; if full optimization including auto-vectorization was enabled, the scalar version should compile to SSE2 or AVX asm.

Comment: Holy Sh*t! That was fast didn't expect a reply at this hour. MSVC is kicking my *ss again because getting rid of that temporary and changing the line to: _DESTi = _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_slli_epi16(_one, p), _source); resulted in about a 2% performance improvement over my original AVX2! Unfortunately when that same tuning is applied to the SSE2 version it also improves by about a 2% improvement. :/

Comment: Really?  An optimized build should compile to the same asm either way.  Avoiding temporary variables usually only helps in a debug build, which is pointless to benchmark.  I'd hope even MSVC to manage optimizing away a temporary that's only used once, especially a loop-invariant that it should just keep in a register as a constant.

Comment: Peter didn't say to just get rid of the temp variable, he said to move its calculation outside the loop. Are you actually compiling with optimizations? The fact that removing a temporary variable improved performance suggests otherwise.

Comment: OK, I think that 2% boost was just a fluke, I ran the code a few more times and the performance is more or less the same as before and I just moved that left shift out of the loop and there is no improvement.

Comment: Also, this isn't your real code; `_mm128_or_si128` is a typo for `_mm_or_si128`.  https://godbolt.org/z/WYhEcsWrj shows MSVC hoisting the shift out of the loop with `-O2` normal optimization enabled.  (It makes a rather inefficient loop, with an ADD and LEA instead of doing the loop condition in terms of a pointer-compare.  So it's more than 4 uops to go through the pipeline for each iteration, so couldn't saturate the store port at 1 store per clock, especially without AVX)

Comment: Also the scaler version doesn't compile to SSE or AVX2 (Yes it's enabled) I think has something to do with that loop being in a function that's being called from multiple threads.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, had to copy and paste, I'm not allowed to share too much, NDA.

Comment: Yeah weird, MSVC on Godbolt doesn't vectorize even with `-O2 -arch:AVX2`.  Better compilers like GCC do, of course.  It can't see at compile time that it's being called from multiple threads.

Comment: BTW, note that your loop bound won't run the vectorized loop when there are exactly 8 elements left; a full vector.  Also note that ORing in a bit is idempotent; instead of scalar cleanup, for arrays larger than 16 bytes you can just do a final 16-byte load/OR/store that overlaps the last full vector if the total size isn't a multiple of the vector width.  (Maybe take some care to avoid a store-forwarding stall).

Comment: Yes I know, I had to modify the posted code for NDA purposes but in the real code the loop counter 'i' is actually the same 'i' variable for the SIMD (SSE or AVX2 depending on ifdefs) and scaler versions, so the scaler version picks up where the SIMD version leaves off.

Comment: Well Thanks for the help guys, I think I need to maybe go to bed it's 6:00 AM (been up all day and all night) where I am now and I think my code is getting worse with my tiredness. Thanks again!